# Will not link, unless inlining method

Tags: c++, boost, linker, inline, blitz++

I am facing a strange error at linking time.

The headers:

**global.h**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <blitz/tinyvec2.h>
typedef blitz::TinyVector<double,3> vettore;

#include "animal.h"
```

**animal.h**

```
#ifndef __ANIMAL_H
#define __ANIMAL_H


//! basic data structure for an animal -------------------------
struct Animal
{
   int age;
public:
   Animal(int _age) : age(_age) {}
};


//! contains info about a pair of animals ----------------------
struct AnimalPairs
{
  vettore distance;

  AnimalPairs( const vettore& _distance ) : distance(_distance) {}
};
typedef std::vector<AnimalPairs> pair_list;


//! data structure for a group of animals ----------------------
class AnimalVector
{
private:
  std::vector<Animal> animals;
  pair_list pairs;

public:
  AnimalVector( const  AnimalVector &other );

};

#endif
```

And here are the `*cpp` files

**main.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"
int main ()
{
   std::cout<< "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

**animal.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"

AnimalVector::AnimalVector( const AnimalVector &other )
{
  pairs = other.pairs;
}
```

To compile I use 
`g++ main.cpp animal.cpp  -I/usr/include/boost -I/fs01/ma01/homes/matc/local/blitz/include`

here is the error I get:

```
/tmp/ccGKHwoj.o: In function `AnimalPairs::AnimalPairs(AnimalPairs const&)':
animal.cpp:(.text._ZN11AnimalPairsC2ERKS_[_ZN11AnimalPairsC5ERKS_]+0x1f):
undefined reference to \`blitz::TinyVector<double,
3>::TinyVector(blitz::TinyVector<double, 3> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For some reasons, if I set the `AnimalVector` constructor to be `inline`, the code will work.
Can someone explain me why?

Edit:
Here is the link to `blitz/tinyvec2.h`
https://github.com/syntheticpp/blitz/blob/master/blitz/tinyvec2.h

Comment: Why are you using `struct`s for `Animal` and `AnimalPairs`? Regarding the linker issue (I'm not familiar with the frameworks used), doesn't it require a library (where `TinyVector` implementation is) to be passed to g++?

Comment: I expect that when the constructor is `inline` it never needs to be instantiated, so whatever the bug is gets skipped.  But without seeing `blitz/tinyvec2.h` I am failing to guess the bug.

Comment: @CristiFati Because I want the age of the animal to be accessible easily, and also the distance between two animals.
The original project is not about animals, but about particles in a physics simulation, where I want to get easy access to data such as positions and velocities.

Comment: @JSF 
thanks for pointing it out. I am adding the link to  blitz/tinyvec2.h to the question.

Comment: I don't recall where documented:  g++ has rules for skipping instantiation of functions (that could have been inlined for some other build choices, but aren't inlined now) on the theory that a well formed program would always instantiate those functions in some other module.  Your program clearly violates the assumptions behind those rules (copy constructor as only defined constructor of `AnimalVector`).  So g++ is skipping instantiating the copy constructor of TinyVector.  But I don't know the exact rule under which it is skipping that.

Comment: Having followed that link, I think the answer is simpler.  The TinyVector copy constructor is declared but not defined in the .h file.  You need to figure out where it is defined and include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tinyvec2.cc` is the file you need to include when you use methods declared in `tinyvec2.h`

I dislike that naming (an include file named `.cc`) and would have overlooked it myself before getting the error you got.

But if you look at the contents of that .cc file, the intended usage is clear.

In similar situations (with very different naming rules for the pairs of files) I use the following coding idiom:

The first include file (their .h) is included by any other .h file that needs any of this.  The second include file is never included by other .h files.

When you get a build error indicating some of it is missing, add an include of the second include file to any .cpp file that gets the build error.

That plan is very effective to keep build speeds fast in mega projects and to minimize circular dependence among complicated interacting template classes.  But it might not be exactly what whoever split tinyvec2 into two include files had in mind.

Bottom line: any module getting the link error you saw needs to have had the .cc file included at compile time, but directly vs. indirectly is up to you.  Including the .cc in your global.h is simpler, and will at worst slow down your build speed (because this .cc does not have circular relationships with your own .h files).